# Always get Broken pipe use sendUrgentData in my Socket Client

Tags: java, sockets

I wrote a `SocketClient` for connect to the socket, and add some callback in it.

```
public class SocketClientV2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SocketClientV2.Listener listener = new SocketClientV2.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void recv(byte[] result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("＝＝＝＝recv something");
            }

            @Override
            public void connected() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("＝＝＝＝＝connected!");
            }

            @Override
            public void disconnect() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("＝＝＝＝＝disconnect!");
            }
        };

        SocketClientV2 client = new SocketClientV2("172.16.16.102", 4444,
                10000, listener);
        byte[] test = new byte[10];
        test[0] = (byte) 0x1c;
        test[1] = (byte) 0xff;
        test[2] = (byte) 0x08;
        client.send(test);

    }

    public interface Listener {
        public void recv(byte[] result);
        public void connected();
        public void disconnect();
    }

    Socket client = null;
    boolean isConnect = false;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    public SocketClientV2() {
    }
    Listener cb = null;
    public SocketClientV2(String site, int port, int timeout, Listener cb) {
        this.cb = cb;
        try {
            client = new Socket(site, port);
            client.setSoTimeout(timeout);
            System.out.println("Client is created! site:" + site + " port:"
                    + port);

            if (isConnected()) {
                isConnect = true;
                if (cb != null) {
                    cb.connected();
                }

                checkConnect();
                listenRecv();
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Socket getClient() {
        return this.client;
    }
    public void closeSocket() {
        try {
            isConnect = false;
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
            client.close();
            client = null;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            client.sendUrgentData(0xff);
            isConnect = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("return false....2");
            isConnect = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void checkConnect() {
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("check connect....1");
                try {

                    while (isConnected()) {

                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    System.out.println("finally....3");
                    if (cb != null) {
                        cb.disconnect();
                    }
                    closeSocket();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }

    private void listenRecv() {
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("listening Recv....");

                try {

                    inputStream = client.getInputStream();
                    while (isConnect) {
                        byte[] result = readStream(inputStream);
                        if (cb != null) {
                            cb.recv(result);
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }
    public void send(final byte[] byteSend) {
        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // System.out.println("sendMsg  coming....");

                if (isConnect) {

                    try {

                        outputStream = client.getOutputStream();
                        outputStream.write(byteSend);
                        outputStream.flush();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        }.start();

    }

    public byte[] readStream(InputStream inStream) throws Exception {
        int count = 0;
        while (count == 0) {
            // System.out.println(0);
            count = inStream.available();
            // if(count!=0)
            // System.out.println(count);
        }
        byte[] b = new byte[count];
        inStream.read(b);
        return b;
    }
}
```

there is one thread `checkConnect` to check the connect status for the socket..

but it will disconnect after running few mins,

```
Client is created! site:172.16.16.102 port:4444
＝＝＝＝＝connected!
check connect....1
listening Recv....
＝＝＝＝recv something
＝＝＝＝recv something
＝＝＝＝recv something
＝＝＝＝recv something
＝＝＝＝recv something
＝＝＝＝recv something
＝＝＝＝recv something
return false....2
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketSendUrgentData(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.sendUrgentData(PlainSocketImpl.java:622)
    at java.net.Socket.sendUrgentData(Socket.java:954)
    at com.udpdemo.multicast.SocketClientV2.isConnected(SocketClientV2.java:100)
    at com.udpdemo.multicast.SocketClientV2.access$0(SocketClientV2.java:98)
finally....3
＝＝＝＝＝disconnect!
    at com.udpdemo.multicast.SocketClientV2$2.run(SocketClientV2.java:121)
java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.available(PlainSocketImpl.java:483)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(SocketInputStream.java:217)
    at com.udpdemo.multicast.SocketClientV2.readStream(SocketClientV2.java:205)
    at com.udpdemo.multicast.SocketClientV2$3.run(SocketClientV2.java:154)
```

so what's problem with my `sendUrgentData`???

Comment: Could have a look at http://www.quickserver.org/ or other open source to see how its done . quick server is light weight and i could follow it in 4-5 hours

Answer (score 1):

'Broken pipe' always means that you wrote to a connection which had already been closed by the peer. It's an application protocol error.

But unless the peer of this client isn't written in Java there is no point in using urgent data in the first place. Java can only receive urgent data 'in-line', i.e. after all the other pending data that had already been sent. And that only happens if the peer calls [setOOBLine(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setOOBInline(boolean)), otherwise

> by default, this option is disabled and TCP urgent data received on a socket is silently discarded.

It's possible you're doing this to *detect* a broken connection. In this case, your dream came true, it worked, and all you have to do is adjust your catch and your code accordingly. But this is not in general a reliable technique.

Other notes:

1. `isConnected()` can never be false at the point you test it after creating the `Socket,` and it never magically becomes false afterwards. You need to revisit *all* the code that calls this method. Most of it doesn't make sense, or relies on false assumptions.
2. Your `readStream()` method spin-loops while `available()` returns zero. There is absolutely no point in this. You're just smoking the CPU. It's also completely at odds with your attempted use of a read timeout, which simply cannot possibly work while this loop is there. The following `read()` call will block until at least one byte of data arrives, or end of stream or an exception occurs. Your present code will never detect end of stream. You need to completely redesign this part of the code as well. It's poor practice to return a byte array for example.
3. That same piece of code completely ignores the count returned by `read().` Never do that.